# Does not recognize Silverlight 4.0 Install

Tags: silverlight

I am running Win 7 64-bit.  I a running IE 9 beta (9.0.7930.16406 )I upgraded to Silverlight 4.0 and for some reason now it does not recognize that I have it installed when I go to Silverlight required web sites.

In my control panel – it clearly states that I have 4.0 installed.  I uninstalled and reinstalled this as well.  However when I go to sites that require silverlight it does not recognize that have Silverlight installed.  And of course when I try to click on install Silverlight I get the following error:  "The same version of silverlight is installed"

Interesting information – I was able to create another account on my computer and get things working.  So this is something tied to my login ID.  And yes I am admin on this box.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked in the "Manage Add-Ons" under your IE Tools menu (that's where it is in version 8) to see if Silverlight is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Are you launching the 32-bit or the 64-bit Internet Explorer process? Silverlight only works in 32-bit browsers.